# Unable to select option with Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, firefox, selenium-ide

I can't select an option with Selenium IDE on my system:

- Mac High Sierra
- Firefox 52
- Selenium IDE 2.9.1
  (I know its old, but (normally) it works and I can't change it!

The select option has the following values:

```
<select name="t2_neurol_mot_l_t1" id="t2_neurol_mot_l_t1">
<option value="">Please select</option>
<option value="1">0</option>
<option value="2">0!</option>
<option value="3">1</option>
<option value="4">1!</option>
<option value="5">2</option>
<option value="6">2!</option>
<option value="7" selected="">3</option>
<option value="8">3!</option>
<option value="9">4</option>
<option value="10">4!</option>
<option value="11">5</option>
<option value="12">5*</option>
<option value="13">NT</option>
<option value="14">NT!</option>
<option value="15">NT*</option>
</select>
```

I need to select the last option NT* with value 15

All of these Commands don't seem to work correctly:

```
| Command       | Target                | Value     |
| select        | id=t2_neurol_mot_l_t1 | label=NT* |

| Command       | Target                | Value     |
| select        | id=t2_neurol_mot_l_t1 | NT*       |

| Command       | Target                | Value     |
| sendKeys      | id=t2_neurol_mot_l_t1 | NT*       |

| Command       | Target                | Value     |
| keyDown       | id=t2_neurol_mot_l_t1 | NT*       |

| Command       | Target                                         | Value     |
| clickAt       | css=select[name=drpReason] option[value=Other] |       |
```

The problem is the command *select* only selects NT, but not NT*

What would works is:

```
| Command       | Target                | Value     |
| select        | id=t2_neurol_mot_l_t1 | value=15  |
```

BUT, I dont have the value, so this option is not possible. I need to selected it with the label...

Any ideas? Could it be a problem of entities, since i can't select NT*, but NT! works...

You can try it on this page:
https://www.saccadic-training.com/is_test.html

Best regards
Beat

Answer (score 0):

As * is used as regex criteria, it is not working. I tried with escape for *, it also didn't work.

But we can select NT* with xpath using click command,

```
| Command       | Target                      | Value     |
| click        | xpath=//option[text()='NT*']|           |
```

Comment: Nice idea. But does it work? I tried this: xpath=//select[@id='t2_neurol_mot_l_t1']/option[text()='NT*'], but i get this error: [error] Specified element is not a Select (has no options)

Comment: sorry for the typo. use click method. I have updated the answer

Comment: yes, i thought so... But that did not work for me... Did it work no your computer?

Comment: It should work 100% for u. Are u getting any error? It works for me in chrome and firefox. Both the selectors

Comment: Try clicking select box first , click   | id=t2_neurol_mot_l_t1 |   |, then click option  | click   | xpath=//option[text()='NT*']|           |

Answer (score 0):

for the records, @Navarasu answers worked for me.

I couldn't select an option from my `<select>` tag -IDE error was that is was not a select element...)

I achieved filling my select with desired option like this :

1. `**command :** click /// **target :** xpath=xpath_of_my_select`
2. `**command :** click /// **target :** xpath=//option[text()='**Foobar**']`
3. any another command so that focus changes

NB : Foobar should be the desired option text value **displayed** on browser (not the "value" attribute in code if different)

NB : Might not work so well if there are 2 `<select>` elements